# Posting JSON to Flask results in 400 Bad Request error

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask

I have a post that works getting a json with the parameters and the columns to get from MongoDB, but when I'm trying to do a LIKE using mongo syntax, it throws:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

This is the POST request:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"parameters":{ "AddressLine1":{$regex:"Rio"}},"columns":{"SalesOrderID":1,"TotalDue":1}}' https://demo.com/api/v1.0/tbles/56a79d15243c488d217f322c
```

or

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"parameters":{ "AddressLine1":{$regex:/Rio/}},"columns":{"SalesOrderID":1,"TotalDue":1}}' https://demo.com/api/v1.0/tbles/56a79d15243c488d217f322c
```

This is the application code:

```
@app.route("/api/v1.0/tables/<idDatasource>", methods=['POST'])
def get_table(idDatasource):
    return 'Hello'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post valid JSON.  All string values, including keys in objects, need to be quoted.  You did not quote `$regex`.

```
{"parameters":{"AddressLine1":{"$regex":"Rio"}},"columns":{"SalesOrderID":1,"TotalDue":1}}
```

If Flask can't decode the JSON data, it raises a 400 error because the request is invalid.